# Triple DES encrypt/decrypt with zero padding in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, padding, 3des

Im looking on web but couldnt find a 3DES crypto example with zero padding in Java. Is it not possible? Can you help me, thanks.
(Im not java developer but i need this. We use PaddingMode.Zeros on .NET)

Answer (score 1):

It's available from the Bouncy Castle provider, but it's not available from Java itself.

The "problem" with the `"ZeroPadding"` option in Bouncy Castle is that it still *always* pads, even if the plaintext length is already a multiple of 8. This is an internal design "issue" with Bouncy. .NET may not always pad with zeros, and PHP *certainly* doesn't always pad with zeros. In that sense there are *two* padding schemes that are called zero padding. That's what you get if no standard exists for the padding scheme.

It's of course relatively easy to implement zero padding yourself. Normally it's not recommended to implement cryptographic primitives, but I guess zero padding can be excluded from that. If your protocol relies on block cipher mode padding for security, you're already in trouble.

You should really upgrade both your algorithm and mode of operation though. Only use this for backwards compatibility, and make sure you can phase it out.

Comment: If you encrypt 16 bytes in .NET with `ZeroPadding`, do you get 16 or 24 bytes? Could you check, I haven't got the .NET dev environment on my new laptop.